# Maximum forward voltage drop per bridge element at 4.0A dc

Tags: voltage, current, switch-mode-power-supply, bridge-rectifier

1. **Can someone tell me what is the meaning of "Maximum forward voltage drop per bridge element at 4.0A dc is 1.1v" in 4 diode bridge rectifier?**

Does it mean that there is a voltage drop of 1.1v per diode or total 1.1v voltage drop for all the 4 diodes together?

[Please refer this link to page 1](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/79808.pdf?_ga=2.173759203.1373971088.1494330466-1367104616.1478756906)

I wanted to know what will be the total voltage drop with this above-mentioned bridge rectifier? I am specifically talking about model number "FL401" in the datasheet.

2. Also, can someone suggest me right ratings for bridge rectifier?
   My requirement is as below.

Vin 7~40v AC or DC to bridge rectifier.
And for my application, I need 3A current

I have chosen the following ratings. Please correct me whether that is right or wrong.

1. No. of Phases: Single
2. Repetitive Reverse Voltage Vrrm Max: 100V
3. Forward Current If(AV): 4A
4. Bridge Rectifier Case Style: SIP
5. Forward Voltage VF Max: 1.1V
6. No. of Pins: 4Pins
7. Operating Temperature Max: 125°C

   3. Also, Please tell me with the above ratings what will be the total voltage drop in the bridge rectifier when I give input as 9v and what will be the output current.

P.S I am not an electrical engineer. Please apologize me if I used any wrong electrical terms or asked any silly questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since only two elements will be on at a time, the drop across the regulator is 1.1 on each side, so a total of 2.2. A little less than that at 3A.

Output current is dictated by the rest of the circuit.

As for the specs.. **Watch your power.** That device may get rather too hot at 3A with no heat sink. I believe Max current shown will be for a heat-sinked installation. 150C is way too hot.....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's my question what does this element indicate here. Does two element indicate directly to two diodes? and you mean during +ve half cycle 2.2v drop and during -ve cycle again 2.2v drop am I, right?

Comment: @kaviarasan correct,, but see my addition to the answer....

Comment: As of now, my device won't draw 3A current. Max will be 1A just for future development I am using 4A rectifier. Can you please tell me does Vrrm of 100v is sufficient for bridge rectifier for the input voltage of max of 40v or do I need to choose other Vrrm ratings.

Comment: @kaviarasan 100V will be fine.